# How to find longest string from a string separated by comma in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, max

I have a string separated by commas `,`. I want to find the longest string from the given string.

```py
words = 'run,barn,abcdefghi,yellow,barracuda,shark,fish,swim'
```

What I did so far

```py
print(max(words.split(','), key=len))
```

And I am getting this output `abcdefghi` but as you can see `abcdefghi` and `barracuda` have same length. So, why I am only getting one instead of two or all.

**Also**

```py
words = 'fishes,sam,gollum,sauron,frodo,balrog'
```

in the above `string` many words have same length. I want to return every one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `zip` len of `word` to `word` then create `dict` from `len` and return largest `len` like below:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> words = 'run,barn,abcdefghi,yellow,barracuda,shark,fish,swim'
>>> dct = defaultdict(list)
>>> lstWrdSplt = words.split(',')
>>> for word, length in (zip(lstWrdSplt,(map(len,lstWrdSplt)))):
...    dct[length].append(word)
    
>>> dct[max(dct)]
['abcdefghi', 'barracuda']

# for more explanation
>>> dct 
defaultdict(list,
            {3: ['run'],
             4: ['barn', 'fish', 'swim'],
             9: ['abcdefghi', 'barracuda'],
             6: ['yellow'],
             5: ['shark']})
```

You can use this as `function` and use `regex` for find only `words` like below:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import re

def mxLenWord(words):
    dct = defaultdict(list)
    lstWrdSplt = re.findall('\w+', words)
    for word, length in (zip(lstWrdSplt,(map(len,lstWrdSplt)))):
        dct[length].append(word.strip())
    return dct[max(dct)]
    
words = 'rUnNiNg ,swimming, eating,biking, climbing'
mxLenWord(words)
```

Output:

```
['swimming', 'climbing']
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the method is quite complicated  !! So just upvoted for now.

Comment: Breaking in `words = 'rUnNiNg ,swimming, eating,biking, climbing'`

Comment: @KunalTanwar welcome, why this is complicated? I find `len` for eac word then create `dict` from `len` to `word` then return largest `len`, and this is `O(n)` only one time iterate words and use key in dict

Comment: @KunalTanwar Ok, you insert `space` I fix it now

Answer (score 2):

Try the below

```
from collections import defaultdict
data = defaultdict(list)
words = 'run,barn,abcdefghi,yellow,barracuda,shark,fish,swim'
for w in words.split(','):
  data[len(w)].append(w)
word_len = sorted(data.keys(),reverse=True)
for wlen in word_len:
  print(f'{wlen} -> {data[wlen]}')
```

output

```
9 -> ['abcdefghi', 'barracuda']
6 -> ['yellow']
5 -> ['shark']
4 -> ['barn', 'fish', 'swim']
3 -> ['run']
```

Comment: Using `data.keys()` is just useless memory consumption.

Answer (score 2):

There're plenty of methods which I find way too complicated for such an easy task. You can solve it using combination of [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) and [`groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```py
from itertools import groupby

words = 'run,barn,abcdefghi,yellow,barracuda,shark,fish,swim'
_, (*longest,) = next(groupby(sorted(words.split(","), key=len, reverse=True), len))
print(longest)
```

To find all words with same length you can use next one-liner:

```py
from itertools import groupby

words = 'fishes,sam,gollum,sauron,frodo,balrog'
words_len = {l: list(w) for l, w in groupby(sorted(words.split(","), key=len), len)}
print(words_len)
```